# How to only show PageFooter on first page for each object?

Tags: .net, activereports

I'm modifying an ActiveReports (for .NET v.2 SP3 Build 4.3.0.1261) report, which is bound to a list of objects. The detail section is set up with two page breaks, so that there are (up to) 3 pages produced for each object.

I say 'up to' because pages 2 & 3 are not relevant to every object, so some objects will generate only one page. I am achieving this from the Detail_Format event by disabling the pagebreaks and reducing the Detail height when only the first page is relevant.

My issue is that I am trying to show the page footer only on the first page for each object, i.e. hide it for pages 2 and 3, but I cannot find a way to do this. I can't just track the page count because the number of pages per object is variable.

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this, even if it means a different approach to playing with the detail layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After shotgunning a lot of the eventhandlers, I managed to figure it out.

Put `PageFooter.Visible = True` in the `Detail.Format` eventhandler,
 and put `PageFooter.Visible = False` in the `Report.PageStart` eventhandler.

In case anyone is interested, my earlier problems were caused by trying to set a counter to zero in the `Detail.Format` eventhandler and increment it the `Report.PageStart` eventhandler and then make the footer not visible when the counter was greater than zero. But due to the timing of the events this meant that

- page 1 had a footer
- page 2 had a footer
- page 3 did not have a footer
- page 1 of the next object did not have a footer

Comment: Did you try to use the pagefooter format event?  You can use a report based counter and then in the pagefooter format event can set the visibility to true or false accordingly. In general the section's property should be edited in the corresponding format's event only.  Are you by any chance also using subreport?

Comment: @RajnishSinha  - I can't remember if I tried the pagefooter format eventhandler or not. It does sound like the best place to make the footer visible or not. The main issue would be whether or not the counter had the correct value when the pagefooter format event fired. I wasn't using a subreport. If I get a chance to try this approach, I'll edit my answer.